# Java: is there an easy way to select a subset of an array?

Tags: java

I have a `String[]` that has at least 2 elements.

I want to create a new `String[]` that has elements 1 through the rest of them. So.. basically, just skipping the first one.

Can this be done in one line? easily?

Answer (score 138, accepted):

Use [`copyOfRange`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange(int%5B%5D,int,int)), available since Java 1.6:

```
Arrays.copyOfRange(array, 1, array.length);
```

Alternatives include:

- [`ArrayUtils.subarray(array, 1, array.length)`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/ArrayUtils.html#subarray-T:A-int-int-) from Apache [commons-lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/)
- [`System.arraycopy(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy(java.lang.Object,int,java.lang.Object,int,int)) - rather unfriendly with the long param list.

Comment: The end index is exclusive

Comment: Wait, so does that mean I need a +1 to the .length?

Comment: No, because arrays are 0 based. Half open ranges and 0 based indexing work together nicely like that.

Comment: Sorry java-folks, but, coming from python code this looks just absurd

Answer (score 24):

```
String[] subset = Arrays.copyOfRange(originalArray, 1, originalArray.length);
```

**See Also:**

- [java.util.Arrays](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html)

Answer (score 7):

Stream API could be used too:

```
String[] array = {"A", "B"};

Arrays.stream(array).skip(1).toArray(String[]::new);
```

However, the answer from Bozho should be preferred.

Comment: @AndreaBergonzo unfortunately, they provided methods for `String[]`, `int[]`, `long[]`, `double[]` but not for `byte[]` :)