# Excluding the first and last element of array

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to display array elements where all elements undergo a change, but the first and last element should remain the same.

Currently I have no idea on how to leave the first and last element alone.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int num = 3;
        int [] array = {2, 3, 2, 5, 3, 1};

        int[] n = increaseValues(array, num);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(n));
    }//end of main
    
    public static int[] increaseValues (int array[], int num){
        int newArray[] = new int[array.length];
        for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
            newArray[i] = array[i] * 3;
        }
        return newArray;
    }//end of method
```

The current output is: 6, 9, 6, 15, 9, 3

Output should be: 2, 9, 6, 15, 9, 1

How should would I implement this?

Comment: this might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/4822280/7344164

Comment: In increaseValues function initialize i with 1 and i should be less than array.length. Later assign newArray[0] = array[0] and newArray[array.lengh - 1] = array[array.length - 1] and return the newArray.

Comment: Narrow down your loop conditions, so you exclude the first and last element from performing the operation, and then manually copying the first and last values to your resulting array. Also, you currently hardcoded the multiplicator value. Correct implementation should be `array[i] * num`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can change the function as this,

```
public static int[] increaseValues (int array[], int num){
    for(int i = 1; i < array.length-1; i++){
        array[i]= array[i] * 3;
    }
    return array;
}
```

So what happens is you will take the `array` object then it will loop from 1st element to `array.length-1` element and do the changes.

the output will look like this,

```
[2, 9, 6, 15, 9, 1]
```

Comment: `int newArray[] = array` -> This is not a copy. Both `newArray` and `array` now point to the same array. To actually copy the array, do `array.clone();` or `Arrays.copyOf(array, array.length);`

Comment: You changed the description to reference, but that defeats the entire point of creating `newArray` to begin with.  You might as well return `void` and just modify the `array` that was passed if you are going to create a pointless reference that modifies the original array anyway.  @maloomeister is correct and the array needs to be _copied_.