# What are some ways to avoid String.substring from returning substring with invalid unicode character?

Tags: java, android

Recently, only I notice that, it is possible for `substring` to return string with invalid unicode character.

For instance

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String text = "_Salade verte";

        /* We should avoid using endIndex = 1, as it will cause an invalid character in the returned substring. */
        // 1 : ?
        System.out.println("1 : " + text.substring(0, 1));

        // 2 : 
        System.out.println("2 : " + text.substring(0, 2));

        // 3 : _
        System.out.println("3 : " + text.substring(0, 3));

        // 4 : _S
        System.out.println("4 : " + text.substring(0, 4));
    }
}
```

I was wondering, when trimming a long string with `String.substring`, what are some good ways to avoid the returned substring from containing invalid unicode?

Comment: I altered your code to use an underscore instead of the first SPACE, for clarity. See [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/4hIJDr).

Comment: @BasilBourque Thanks. I amend my sample code to make the result clearer.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## `char` obsolete

The [`char`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html) type has been [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) since [Java 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#J2SE_1.2), essentially broken. As a [16-bit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/16-bit_computing) value, `char` is physically incapable of representing [most characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(Unicode)).

Your discovery suggests that the [`String#substring`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,int)) command is `char` based. Hence the problem shown in your code.

## Code point

Instead, use [code point](https://ideone.com/4hIJDr) integer numbers when working with individual characters.

```
int[] codePoints = "_Salade".codePoints().toArray() ;
```

> [129382, 95, 83, 97, 108, 97, 100, 101]

Extract the first character’s code point.

```
int codePoint = codePoints[ 0 ] ;
```

> 129382

Make a single-character `String` object for that code point.

```
String firstCharacter = Character.toString( codePoint ) ;
```

> 

You can [grab a subset of that `int` array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4822256/642706) of code points.

```
int[] firstFewCodePoints = Arrays.copyOfRange( codePoints , 0 , 3 ) ;
```

And make a `String` object from those code points.

```
String s = 
    Arrays
        .stream( firstFewCodePoints ) 
        .collect( StringBuilder::new , StringBuilder::appendCodePoint , StringBuilder::append )
        .toString();
```

> _S

Or we can use a [constructor of `String`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#%3Cinit%3E(int%5B%5D,int,int)) to take a subset of the array.

```
String result = new String( codePoints , 0 , 3 ) ;
```

> _S

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/CcoUuV).

Comment: Nice workaround. But, I was wondering, is there a way to know what should be the `to` value for `Arrays.copyOfRange`, so that the resultant string length will not exceed maxLength? The old way of doing is via `string.substring(0, maxLength)`, but that may resultant invalid unicode code at the end of string.

Comment: Char is not obsolete and will never be. It's just no one gave any promises that a single char will correspond to a single Unicode code point.

Answer (score 5):

The answer by Basil nicely shows that you should work with code points instead of `char`s.

A `String` does not store Unicode code points internally, so there is no way to know which characters belong together forming a Unicode code point, without inspecting the actual contents of the string.

#### Unicode-aware substring

Here is a Unicode-aware substring method. Since `codePoints()` returns an `IntStream`, we can utilize the `skip` and `limit` methods to extract a portion of the string.

```java
public static String unicodeSubstring(String string, int beginIndex, int endIndex) {
    int length = endIndex - beginIndex;
    int[] codePoints = string.codePoints()
        .skip(beginIndex)
        .limit(length)
        .toArray();
    return new String(codePoints, 0, codePoints.length);
}
```

This is what happens in the abovementioned snippet of code. We stream over the Unicode code points, skipping the first *beginIndex* bytes and limiting the stream to *endIndex − beginIndex*, and then convertb to `int[]`. The result is that the int array contains all Unicode code points from *beginIndex* up to *endIndex*.

At last, the `String` class contains a nice constructor to construct a `String` from an `int[]` with code points, so we use it to get the String.

---

Of course, you could tweak the method to be a little more strict by rejecting out-of-bounds values:

```java
if (endIndex < beginIndex) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("endIndex < beginIndex");
}
int length = endIndex - beginIndex;
int[] codePoints = string.codePoints()
    .skip(beginIndex)
    .limit(length)
    .toArray();
if (codePoints.length < length) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException(
        "begin %s, end %s, length %s".formatted(beginIndex, endIndex, codePoints.length)
    );
}
return new String(codePoints, 0, codePoints.length);
```

[<kbd>Online demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/MCNWoI)

Answer (score 1):

I would like to provide another point of view, on how to implement `substring` which is able to guarantee the returned string contains valid unicode.

Unlike answer provided by @MC Emperor, my code treats

length as 2 (Instead of 1 by @MC Emperor)

This is important, to ensure the new function's behavior will resemble as close as old `String.substring`.

```
public static int length(String string) {
    if (string == null) {
        return 0;
    }
    return string.length();
}

public static String limitLength(String string, int maxLength) {
    int stringLength = length(string);

    if (stringLength <= maxLength) {
        return string;
    }

    List<Integer> codePointList = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int offset = 0; offset < maxLength; ) {
        final int codePoint = string.codePointAt(offset);

        final int charCount = Character.charCount(codePoint);

        if ((offset + charCount) > maxLength) {
            break;
        }

        codePointList.add(codePoint);

        offset += charCount;
    }

    int[] codePoints = new int[codePointList.size()];

    for (int i = 0; i < codePoints.length; i++)
    {
        codePoints[i] = codePointList.get(i);
    }

    String result = new String(codePoints, 0, Math.min(maxLength, codePoints.length));

    return result;
}
```

The code performance might not be efficient, if the `maxLength` value is large. But, I can't think of a much better way now. If you know a better way, feel free to amend the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is by design. Java provides many ways to extract individual Unicode code points from a string if it's necessary: see the [Oracle tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/characterClass.html).

However, most of the time it's not needed since you get the string index from a method like `String.indexOf(String s)` or `Matcher.start()`. In this case the resulting index won't point in the middle of a code point (as long as the argument `s` is a valid Unicode string).

It's even more common to work with regular expressions where string indexes don't come up altogether.