Limit the string length while ensuring Unicode validity
I wish to limit the string length while ensuring Unicode validity.
In Java, I am using this function - https://stackoverflow.com/a/70208806/72437
Java
public static int length(String string) {
    if (string == null) {
        return 0;
    }
    return string.length();
}

public static String limitLength(String string, int maxLength) {
    int stringLength = length(string);

    if (stringLength <= maxLength) {
        return string;
    }

    List<Integer> codePointList = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int offset = 0; offset < maxLength; ) {
        final int codePoint = string.codePointAt(offset);

        final int charCount = Character.charCount(codePoint);

        if ((offset + charCount) > maxLength) {
            break;
        }

        codePointList.add(codePoint);

        offset += charCount;
    }

    int[] codePoints = new int[codePointList.size()];

    for (int i = 0; i < codePoints.length; i++)
    {
        codePoints[i] = codePointList.get(i);
    }

    String result = new String(codePoints, 0, codePoints.length);

    return result;
}

Here is the result
String s = "‍‍éन्म‍क्षि";
for (int i=1; i<30; i++) {
    Log.i("CHEOK", i + " -> " + limitLength(s, i));
}

1 -> 
2 -> 
3 -> 
4 -> 
5 -> 
6 -> 
7 -> ‍
8 -> ‍
9 -> ‍
10 -> ‍‍
11 -> ‍‍
12 -> ‍‍
13 -> ‍‍é
14 -> ‍‍éन
15 -> ‍‍éन्
16 -> ‍‍éन्म
17 -> ‍‍éन्म
18 -> ‍‍éन्म
19 -> ‍‍éन्म‍
20 -> ‍‍éन्म‍
21 -> ‍‍éन्म‍
22 -> ‍‍éन्म‍क
23 -> ‍‍éन्म‍क्
24 -> ‍‍éन्म‍क्ष
25 -> ‍‍éन्म‍क्षि
26 -> ‍‍éन्म‍क्षि
27 -> ‍‍éन्म‍क्षि
28 -> ‍‍éन्म‍क्षि
29 -> ‍‍éन्म‍क्षि


In Swift, it can better handle unicode
Swift
extension String {
    func prefix(_ maxLength: Int) -> String {
        let substring: Substring = self.prefix(maxLength)
        return String(substring)
    }
}

let text = "‍‍éन्म‍क्षि"
for i in (1...10) {
    print(">>>> text \(i) : \(text.prefix(i))")
}

>>>> text 1 : 
>>>> text 2 : ‍‍
>>>> text 3 : ‍‍é
>>>> text 4 : ‍‍éन्म
>>>> text 5 : ‍‍éन्म‍
>>>> text 6 : ‍‍éन्म‍क्षि
>>>> text 7 : ‍‍éन्म‍क्षि
>>>> text 8 : ‍‍éन्म‍क्षि
>>>> text 9 : ‍‍éन्म‍क्षि
>>>> text 10 : ‍‍éन्म‍क्षि

May I know, how I can improve my Java version of code, so that it behave similar to Swift's?

Show your length(string) method implementation

Sorry. I missed that. Updated.

You probably (not totally sure what the motivation is in your code) want return string.codePoints().count(); Possibly with something like the following for your key method body: return string.codePoints().limit(maxLength).collect(StringBuilder::new, StringBuilder::appendCodePoint, StringBuilder::append).toString();

It has to be said, there's not much mystery about all this. What is more critical is when those Strings become bytes. Then the length can be very much more unpredictable and cross-grapheme cutting might be an issue, resulting in corrupted encoding. But none of that is addressed in your code

You are mixing char with code points. Your length method counts char values, but then you use that count to access code points. Do not mix those. Example: FACE WITH MEDICAL MASK "" has one code point but a String#length of 2. As a 16-bit value, a single char value is physically unable to represent characters outside of the BMP, unable to represent most characters. The char type has been essentially broken since Java 2 (when Unicode expanded beyond the BMP), legacy since Java 5.
